# animate the position switching of 2 imageViews

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

We're trying to animate the switching of position of 2 imageview views along the z access. The 2 imageViews are the 2 at the to of the screen[image]
So far I've tried using a CAAnimationGroup for position and rotation but it's only show one of the images and it appears to position and rotation are off. This is what the code looks like:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var meMatchImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var theyMatchImageView: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let groupAnimation = CAAnimationGroup()
    groupAnimation.beginTime = 0.0
    groupAnimation.duration = 1.5
    groupAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut
)
    groupAnimation.delegate = self


    let rotationAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.values = [0, 0.14, 0]
    rotationAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 0]

    let positionZAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.z")
    positionZAnimation.fromValue = -1
    positionZAnimation.toValue = 1

    let point0 = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    let point1 = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 110, y: -20))


    let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    positionAnimation.values = [point0, point1, point0]
    positionAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 0]

    groupAnimation.animations = [rotationAnimation, positionAnimation, positionZAnimation]

    meMatchImageView.layer.add(groupAnimation, forKey: "switch")
    theyMatchImageView.layer.add(groupAnimation, forKey: "switch")
  }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There were at least two issues in your code.

First of all, you're applying the same animation (regarding `position`, `rotation` and `position.z`) on the two `ImageView`, as soon as the animation start, they'll perform exactly identical animations thus in the whole process they were completely stacked.

Second you're using the `keyTimes` attribute wrong, looks like your original design would be `[0, 0.5, 1]`.